# Java regex require at least one letter and one digit. Also allow any special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I tried searching for a regex which can validate if a string contains at least one letter and one digit and there can be any special character as well with a minimum 8 length.

I tried below regex but it checking

- One digit
- One letter
- @ and - special symbol

  ```
  (?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){1,})(?=(?:.*[@-]){0,})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){1,})^[a-zA-Z0-9@-]*$
  ```

But I want it can allow any special characters (Special chars are optional but at least one letter and one digit must be there in string.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regex. It's easier just to iterate the string character-by-character:

```
boolean foundDigit = false;
boolean foundLetter = false;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
  if (Character.isDigit(c)) { foundDigit = true; }
  else if (Character.isLetter(c)) { foundLetter = true; }
}
return str.length() >= 8 && foundDigit && foundLetter;
```

The requirement of "optional special character" seems to be unnecessary to check, since you don't specify that the string can only contain certain characters, and it doesn't have to be there.

Comment: WoW!! It's great; I didn't even think that solution can be so simple. +1

Answer (score 1):

The same logic as @Andy Turner but using streams:

```
public static boolean validiate(String str){
    return str.chars().count() >7 && 
           str.chars().filter(c->Character.isLetter(c)).count()>1 &&
           str.chars().filter(c->Character.isDigit(c)).count()>1;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your original question but if you like to use streams in android development it might be worth going throug this article[https://medium.com/@nicopasso/java-8-stream-on-android-c629e4237d5f](https://medium.com/@nicopasso/java-8-stream-on-android-c629e4237d5f) which discuss the [https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API).